# Rails and Cucumber with Fixtures is not loading changes in Fixtures

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber, fixtures

I have created fixtures located in `spec/fixtures/` directory. I am running my Cucumber tests without any problem until I needed to change a value in my fixtures, but I cannot see the changes when I run the test. I am running using:

`cucumber features/my_feature_cucumber.feature`

I tried also:

`bundle exec cucumber features/my_feature_cucumber.feature`

and I am using **byebug** to verify the contents in the database.

All the time in has the same data as though there were no changes in the fixtures. I am losing something about the way it is loaded in every execution?

Comment: After a while the changes were reflected in the database, but I still don't understand what triggered the changes and what I have to do to see them instantly. If any of you know something about it I will be thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, maybe it was a silly question, but I would like to share the answer in case anyone else face this scenario in the future.

The answer is in the fixtures itself. They are created under `spec` directory, which means they are part of `Rspec`. Cucumber uses it but he doesn't reload them. So the way to see the changes reflected in Cucumber is simple executing `Rspec`, he will make the reloads.

```
rspec
```

or

```
bundle exec rspec
```

works to see the changes reflected in Cucumber.